# Minimum spanning tree in python

Tags: python, graph

I'm having problems calculating the minimum spanning tree of a simple graph using the following python snippet. It is trivial to do it by hand and I've included an image of the graph and the minimum spanning tree from the textbook.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import minimum_spanning_tree

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
friendships = [
    ('A', 'B',{'weight':2}),
    ('A', 'E',{'weight':10}),
    ('A', 'D',{'weight':1}),
    ('A', 'C',{'weight':4}),
    ('B', 'D',{'weight':1}),
    ('C', 'D',{'weight':4}),
    ('D', 'E',{'weight':7}),
    ('D', 'F',{'weight':10}),
    ('E', 'F',{'weight':8}),
    ('D', 'G',{'weight':7}),
    ('C', 'G',{'weight':3}),
    ('E', 'G',{'weight':5}),

]

G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(friendships)
X = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')

X = csr_matrix(X)
Tcsr = minimum_spanning_tree(X)
Tcsr.toarray().astype(int)
```

If you run the code, you get "A-B-G-F-E-C-D". More like a list.

Visually, the graph and the answer from the book are the following:

[image: Original_Graph]

[image: MST]

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Your posted code does not result in a list of node labels.  If you bother to `print` the final output, it's a list of edges with their weights.  You have a list of edges: a spanning tree.  As `Gorka` noted, you omitted one of the 13 graph edges in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

A minimum spanning tree is a subset of the edges of the original graph, so "A-B-G-F-E-C-D" cannot be a solution (unless the solution is a path).
You are missing the edge (F, G) in the *friendships* list. Now you will obtain:

```
  (0, 3)    1.0
  (0, 4)    4.0
  (1, 3)    1.0
  (2, 6)    5.0
  (4, 6)    3.0
  (5, 6)    3.0
```

and following the order of the nodes in the *friendships* adjacency list, this is equivalent to:

```
  (A, D)    1.0
  (A, C)    4.0
  (B, D)    1.0
  (E, G)    5.0
  (C, G)    3.0
  (F, G)    3.0
```

Note that, the minimum spanning tree of a graph is not unique. Rather than checking the edges of the obtained tree, you need to check that the weight of the tree is the same as in the example of the book, i.e., 17.